# value is undefined in emberjs nested view

Tags: javascript-framework, ember.js

i have a script handlebar..

```
<script id="ownerItem" data-template-name='ownerItem' type="text/x-handlebars">
    {{value.UserName}} &nbsp;<button {{action "remove" on="click"}}>Remove</button>
</script>
```

And its view..

```
ResAdmin.ownerView = Ember.View.extend({
    templateName: 'ownerItem',
    remove: function() {
      var selectedRest;
      selectedRest = ResAdmin.adminController.get('selectedRestaurant');
      alert(value.RestaurantOwnerID);
      return $.ajax({
        url: '/api/RestaurantOwner/' + value.RestaurantOwnerID,
        cache: false,
        type: 'delete',
        data: {
          RestaurantID: selectedRest.RestaurantID,
          MethodOverride: 'delete'
        },
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        success: function(data) {
          return ResAdmin.adminController.getRestaurantList();
        }
      });
    }
  });
```

and in some other view i am using this view like

```
  {{#each ResAdmin.adminController.selectedRestaurant.Owners}}
            {{view ResAdmin.ownerView valueBinding="this" content="this"}} 
        {{/each}}
```

but i am getting error(value is not defined) when user click on remove button of my nested view...can anybody help me ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

value is a property of the ownerView so you need to qualify it with this.get('value')

e.g.

```
this.get('value').RestaurantOwnerId
```